# How to enlarge partition volume after moving OS image to a new disk by dd command?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, disk

I use Cent OS 7.

I recently moved from an old HDD disk (~900GB space) to a new SSD device (~1.1TB space) by using the `dd` command.

Currently the system is not fully utilizing the space capacity provided by SSD.

The following figure shows the output of `fdisk /dev/nvme1n1`, after pressing <kbd>p</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

(When I try to allocated till the sector number = 2344225968, it emits the error message: out of range)

There are 2344225968 sectors available but the **partition 4** ends up with end sector = 1951170526.

How can I recover the full space?

Comment: Can you please (1) post the text as text formatted as code, not as pictures, and (2) edit the question to show the output of `sudo parted /dev/nvme1n1 -- unit s print free`?

Comment: Boot with a livecd and run gparted to extend the partition